# Adding Keys To Child Element In React

Tags: reactjs

I get a message as following:
'Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop'.

Any way to automatically add keys to the elements inside 'content'?

```
const ArticlesArray = [
  {
    id: 2,
    title: `title`,
    subtitle: `subtitle`,
    linkUrl: `articles/2`,
    content: [
    <h5>text</h5>,
      <p>
        more text
      </p>,

      <p>
        and some more text
      </p>
    ]
  },
];

return (
    <div className="article-container">
      <h3> {filteredArticle[0].title} </h3>
      <h4> {filteredArticle[0].subtitle} </h4>
      <hr />
      <div>
      { filteredArticle[0].content.map(p => 
        p)
      }
        </div>
    </div>
  );
```

EDIT: Solved

```
<div>
        {filteredArticle[0].content.map((p, idx) => (
          <div key={idx}>{p}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try with adding unique key to the your Components

```
$return(
    <CustomComponents 
        key={item.id}     //unique key id
    />
);
```

or

```
$render() {
return (
  <ol>
    {this.props.results.map((result, i) => (
      <li key={i}>{result.data}</li>
    ))}
  </ol>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest rethinking your use case as it might be an anti pattern. To answer your quesiton: You can loop through your contents array and set a key for each entry quite easily, e.g

```
ArticlesArray[0].content = ArticlesArray[0].content.map((e, idx) => (e.key = idx, e));
```

The above code sets the key of each element in the content array to its index.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really completed. If I'm to guess, you are trying to render the component based on `ArticlesArray`, via the `map` method?

If that's the case, you can refer to below

```js
render () {
  return ArticlesArray.map(ele => (
    <MyCustomsComponent key={ele.id} ... /> // <<<<==== HERE
  ))
}
```

The idea is that, for each and every component that you're trying to render, gives it a prop `key` and assign a unique value which allows React to identify the element in that array